# python : append to data use json.dumps

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create JSON file. using json.dumps and success printing.
I have a question.

The format I wanted was

```
channel_info = OrderedDict()
table = OrderedDict()
table2 = OrderedDict()

channel_info["KIND1"] = pkind[2].text
table[ptime[10].text] = pnk[11].text
table[ptime[11].text] = pnk[12].text
channel_info["TABLE1"] = table

channel_info["KIND2"] = pkind[2].text
table2[ptime[10].text] = pnk[11].text
table2[ptime[11].text] = pnk[12].text
channel_info["TABLE2"] = table2
```

result:

```
{
"KIND1": "xxxx",
"TABLE1": {
    "09:10": "aaaa",
    "10:10": "bbbb"
},
"KIND2": "yyyy",
"TABLE2": {
    "09:10": "cccc",
    "10:10": "dddd"
}
```

}

How to output the same format using a while loop?
The names of the JSON objects? KIND1, TABLE1, KIND2, TABLE2 and so on ...
I wonder how you can change these names dynamically using a while loop.
thank you.

Comment: Please make it clear what you expected in the question?

Comment: At first I would expect the index to change. With your code  `KIND1` and `KIND2` should be the same.

Comment: So basically, you want to increment the tablenames as in TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3, etc (the same goes for KIND), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (assuming `table` dictionary is static over each loop, as it seems in the example you give):

```
channel_info = dict()
# n_tables is the number of iterations you need
for i in range(n_tables):
    table = dict()
    channel_info["KIND%s" % (i+1)] = pkind[1].text
    table[ptime[10].text] = pnk[11].text
    table[ptime[11].text] = pnk[12].text
    channel_info["TABLE%s" % (i+1)] = table
```

You don't need the table name dynamically since you assign it to a dictionary key.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if I understood your question right:

```
...
i=0
no_of_tables = 4 
while i<=no_of_tables:
  table_counter = i+1
  table_counter = str(table_counter)
  kind = 'KIND' + table_counter
  table = 'TABLE' + table_counter
  channel_info[kind] = pkind[2].text
  table[ptime[10].text] = pnk[11].text
  table[ptime[11].text] = pnk[12].text
  channel_info[table] = table
```

Note: I know it can be optimized, but for the sake of simplicity I left it as is.

Comment: but it have a problem.  [TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment]. i don't know why this error. Anyway, Thanks for helping us troubleshoot